# Django server able to retrieve all get query parameters but apache not

Tags: python, django, get, django-queryset

Why is it printing only two values ??

Here is my output:

[image]

This is views.py

```
import json
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import Context, RequestContext
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response, get_object_or_404


def callback(request):
    verification_code = request.GET.get('verification_code')
    userid = request.GET.get('userid')
    userid1 = request.GET.get('userid1')
    userid2 = request.GET.get('userid2')
    userid3 = request.GET.get('userid3')

    context = {
       'verification_code': verification_code,
       'userid': userid,
       'userid1': userid1,
       'userid2': userid2,
       'userid3': userid3,
    }
   return render_to_response('wings/callback.html', context,  
                    context_instance=RequestContext(request))


def detail(request):

    response_data = {}
    response_data['result'] = 'failed'
    response_data['message'] = 'You messed up'

    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response_data), content_type="application/json")
```

Here is callback.html

```
 <!-- callback.html -->

verification_code: {{verification_code }}<br />                                                                                            
userid: {{userid }} <br />
userid1: {{userid1 }} <br />
userid2: {{userid2 }} <br />
userid3: {{userid3 }} <br />
```

**Edit:**

As suggested I edited and put `<br/>` but no change

**Edit:**
I am getting all values when try with django server but as soon as i shift to apache ,it shows this weird behaviour

Comment: print `request.GET` and see what it contains

Comment: its NULL ... please see my edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok ... That was a silly mistake on my part. Developing with django default server for quite some time, I get into habit of changing file and check output but that is not the case with apache. You have to restart server each and every time. Sorry for all the mess.

All i needed to do is-

`$ service apache2 restart`